# in PHP How to regex preg_match specific HTML tag value from same type value tags

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

in PHP How to regex preg_match the specific tag value from same type and value tags.

Here are some html tags and i want to fetch last tag value from via regex preg_match

```
</tr>
<tr class="flow">
<td>14.1%</td>
<td>13.2%</td>
<td>13.6%</td>
<td>14.1%</td>
<td>14.0%</td>
<td>14.0%</td>
<td>14.1%</td> <== i want to fetch this last <td> tag value with regex, how ?
</tr>
</tbody>

If I preg_match `'/<tr class="flow">(.*?)<\/td>/s'`; 
but then it will fetch first `<td>` tag value 
and if preg_match `'/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/s'`; 
then it will fetch all `<td>` tags values. 

So how I can fetch last `<td>` value?

I mean I want something like to `preg_match` in reverse mode 
like this `'/</tbody>(.*?)<\td>/s'`; or maybe anything else to do?


This is the small part of page and page contain 100's of other <td> tags
so you must have to do something preg_match with 
between </tbody> and <td> in reverse mode ...OR.. 
Between <tr class="flow">  </tbody> in forward mode.
```

But I can't figure out how? You help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: No your answer not solve my problem it to comlicated to undestand. So please give me an example here how i can preg_match the last <td> tag value. what formula i have to use ?

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('|\<tr class="flow"\>(.*?)\</tr\>|s', $input_text, $match);
$filterd_input_text = $match[1];
preg_match_all('|\<td\>(.*?)\</td\>|', $filterd_input_text, $matches);
$value = end($matches[1]);
var_dump($value);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('|<td>(.*?)</td>.*</tbody>|s', $t, $matches);
```

Comment: Sorry it can't help because this is the small part of html page and html page contain 100's of other <td> tags so you have to do something preg_match with between </tbody> and <td>

Comment: @smallbee can you post the url of complete html? or paste it in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: You could use two preg_match_all. The first to find the relevant html. And the second to find your value

Comment: Can you please edit your answer again to give me an example here, you help will be appreciated.